# .Net 6 Web API returning a wrong remote IP address through Apache proxy

Tags: c#, apache, asp.net-core, reverse-proxy, ip-address

I have a .Net 6 C# web API that needs to verify the client IP address in some controller methods to reinforce the security. The self-contained published application run as a local service on Linux and is accessible through Apache which is used as a reverse proxy.

In my controller methods I use this line to get the IP address:

`string currentIp = _httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();`

In the program.cs file I added this:

```
builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});
```

And finally in my Apache configuration file there is:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass "/api/" http://127.0.0.1:5000/
        ProxyPassReverse "/api/" http://127.0.0.1:5000/
        ...
```

The problem is that the value of the remote IP address (currentIp variable) in my controller is always the same, something like "165.30.0.1" which is a device (a router ?) on the server network "165.30.0.0" I guess. The server address on this network is "165.30.0.100" through a VPN by the way.

I have already tried the following in the C# "builder.Services.Configure" above:

```
options.ForwardLimit = null; // Or = 2
options.KnownProxies.Clear(); // Or .Add() with some IP addresses
options.KnownNetwork.Clear(); // Or .Add() with some IP addresses
```

I have also tested the Apache configuration file above with:

```
RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-For" expr=%{REMOTE_ADDR}
```

But always this damn "165.30.0.1" IP address is returned and never the client's real IP address.

The server is controlled by a contractor so could it be a router or firewall protection that generates this behavior or is it caused by my configuration ?

Comment: Do you call `UseForwardedHeaders()` in your middleware configuration? Having your startup code from Program.cs would be helpful to answer this question.

Comment: Sorry I have forgotten to write it done but yes I used it.

Comment: The good news is that my problem is solved. The server providing company was blocking the remote IP address forwarding. After calling them, they told me that every functionality is blocked by default for security reason and needs to be unblocked one by one. Now I'm getting the user IP in my controller code. Thank you anyway! Kind regards.